# How to use intersect() method of Node Class in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

JavaFX Node class provides two intersect methods:

```
 intersects(Bounds localBounds);
```

and

```
 intersects(double localX, double localY, double localWidth, double localHeight);
```

When and how can I use these methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as it name tells it is used to determine if a node is intersected with other node or not..

Example : If you're going to develop Zen pong game in javafx ,if  ball hits the wall behind paddle then game over.

Code :

```
   private  Circle ball;
   private  Rectangle wall;
   if(ball.intersects(wall.getBoundsInLocal()) {
        //game over
    }
```

Comment: This is only correct if both nodes share a coordinate system. Otherwise, you need to transform the bounds before testing for collision.